# How to control SQLDriverConnect timeout in case network down?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use C++ SQLDriverConnect to connect to our backend MS SQL Server. Via the attributes it is possible to set a parameter for a login timeout (SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT), which, defines how long it takes before the SQLDriverConnect (which is kind of the login) takes.

Now, if I stop the SQL service on the server, this timeout is respected, and exactly after X seconds after calling the function I wil get my connect faillure, which is of course correct.
However, if I do not stop the service, but, disable the network adapter from the server, our pull out the network cable of the server, the SQLDriverConnect does not respect this timeout, and only returns a lot later.

For example, when setting the timeout to 5 seconds, the SQLDriverConnect only returns after 53 seconds if the SQL server is down.

I know this can be solved by making my own asynchronous connect, which I can always make return after X seconds, but, if possible, I would prefer not to do this and just use the provided functions and options to control the connection.

I assume the delay is caused by the network stack that is trying to find the host, but, my idea is that we use a higher level API with a timeout just to make sure we don't have to worry about those kind of things...

Any ideas on how this can be "fixed"?

thx in advance

Wim

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SQL_ATTR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT?

Comment: Hi, we tried all possible connection attributes, but, none of them solved the issue. We found out that the reason for this behaviour is actually the windows tcp/ip stack that is "busy" searching on the network for the server, and it is a network time out it is waiting for. So SQL connection cannot change/modify the behaviour, it is in the sockets library most likely. Anyway, we solved by going to an asynchronous handling, so that our main thread continuous after the timeout we set, irrespective whether the blocking is on network, Sql or any other components... it always works

Comment: Nice. Yeah I agree, async I/O is the way to go.